# ClassNotFoundException in SncRedisExtension Factory" from namespace "Predis\Profile" after composer update

Tags: php, symfony, predis

Today after update composer packages I get error message.

```
ClassNotFoundException in SncRedisExtension.php line 158:
Attempted to load class "Factory" from namespace "Predis\Profile".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Buzz\Message\Factory\Factory"?
```

This configuration work some time  - now stop without any changes in my side.

here is my Composer.json packages

```
     "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",

    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "1.*@dev",

    "html2text/html2text": "dev-master",

    "liuggio/statsd-client-bundle": "1.6.*",

    "weotch/phpthumb": "dev-master",

    "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "*",
    "oh/google-map-form-type-bundle": "dev-master",
    "meenie/javascript-packer": "dev-master",
    "natxet/CssMin": "dev-master",
    "apy/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",

    "webit/sms-common": "dev-master",
    "webit/smsapi": "dev-master",
    "webit/smsapi-bundle": "dev-master",

    "ddeboer/data-import": "dev-master",
    "endroid/qrcode": "1.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.2",


    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "*@dev",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "0.14.*",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.5",
    "fpn/tag-bundle": "^0.9.0",

    "snc/redis-bundle": "~1.1",

    "instaclick/translation-editor-bundle": "dev-master",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "~1.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",

    "payum/payum-bundle": "0.14.*",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "*@stable",
    "payum/offline": "0.14.*",
    "predis/predis": "0.8.x-dev",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^2.6",
    "dzasa/open-exchange-rates": "dev-master",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.2.1"
```

what can be a reason  ? I see this file in github ->

https://github.com/nrk/predis/tree/v1.0/src/Profile

but it is not downloaded on composer update

here is files list

```
/PhpstormProjects/welasy/vendor/predis/predis/lib/Predis/Profile$ ls -la
razem 116
drwxrwxr-x  2 grek grek  4096 kwi 20 21:53 .
drwxrwxr-x 16 grek grek  4096 kwi 20 21:53 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek  1444 kwi 20 21:53 ServerProfileInterface.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek  5992 kwi 20 21:53 ServerProfile.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek  6521 kwi 20 21:53 ServerVersion12.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek  9342 kwi 20 21:53 ServerVersion20.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek 10846 kwi 20 21:53 ServerVersion22.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek 11033 kwi 20 21:53 ServerVersion24.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek 12410 kwi 20 21:53 ServerVersion26.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek 13595 kwi 20 21:53 ServerVersion28.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek 13659 kwi 20 21:53 ServerVersion30.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 grek grek   711 kwi 20 21:53 ServerVersionNext.php
```

Answer (score 18):

ok i found this problem - https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/pull/172#issuecomment-117117440

just replace predis in composer.json to

"predis/predis": "^1.0"

Comment: This fixes the issue. Thanks buddy :)